# Parsing dyanmic json file into hashmap of object

Tags: java, android, json

I have returned json as following Columns A , B, C , D as Strings represent my keys to array of json objects Note: columns is dynamic could be returned as A , B, C , D , F, G , or A,B  doesn't have fixed shape:

[image]

I could retrieve these data from JSON as `HashMap<String,String>`
but is there are any way to retrieve it as `List<Columns>` and every `columns` as JSON object

Comment: You can deserialise it to `Map` and convert to required format after deserialisation. How `Columns` class looks like? Do you want to deserialise to `List<com.google.gson.JsonObject>?` Could you also change image on `JSON` payload?

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, this can be achieved using one line of map-expressions. I've ported it to Java for you. The code prints a HashMap containing lists of Objects assigned to the column's names.

```java
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"columns\":[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\"],\"data\":[{\"A\":\"1test1\",\"B\":\"1test2\",\"C\":\"1test3\"},{\"A\":\"2test1\",\"B\":\"2test2\",\"C\":\"2test3\"},{\"A\":\"3test1\",\"B\":\"3test2\",\"C\":\"3test3\"}]}");
JSONArray cols = obj.getJSONArray("columns");
JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("data");

HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> columnsMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Object column : cols) {
    ArrayList<Object> columnList = new ArrayList<>(data.length());

    for (Object j : data) {
        JSONObject rowObject = (JSONObject) j;

        columnList.add(rowObject.get((String) column));
    }

    columnsMap.put((String) column, columnList);
}

System.out.println(columnsMap);
```